# Maven: Include dependencies from pom.xml located in one of the dependencies

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am new to maven and was wondering how to include dependencies that exists in a pom.xml file located in one of my dependencies (without looking into that pom.xml and just doing a copy paste of the depencies into my pom.xml file)?

So this is what I want to achieve:

My project structure:

[image]

I want to somehow in pom.xml tell maven to also make sure to include the dependencies inside of libPom.xml in the final jar file.

Thanks

Comment: maven automatically include dependencies of dependencies. If they are added as dependencies in the pom.xml

Comment: sounds like an answer @Jens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven automatically includes transitive dependencies.

Just build with `mvn clean install` and have a look at the resulting jar file.

Caveat: the pom in the included library needs to be correct, and only dependencies with the correct (or default) `classifier` will be included.

To see how it works, try this:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven automatically installs all related dependencies.

In your case `mvn clean compile` and `mvn clean install` will be enough to load all the related dependencies.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: It does not help to duplicate an existing answer.

Comment: @JFMeier: My bad.. I haven't seen other answers.